# Occasionally Jenkins Configuration Matrix jobs report failure on success

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

### General Symptoms

We use Jenkins to build & test on multiple platforms.  We use the Configuration Matrix plugin to help with this.  Occasionally (increasingly often) Jenkins will mark the Configuration Matrix master job or subjobs as failed when the jobs seem to have succeeded (the console output reports success).  We have no idea why this is happening.  Any suggestions?

### Some clues:

- The exit code of the Jenkins job's script is not relevant. We've had test sub-jobs that simply exit 0 and they can still exhibit this bad behavior.
- The failures are bunchy. They seem to come in groups.
- The failures tend to effect our Windows platforms more heavily but the issue occurs on our Mac nodes as well.
- The failures clump on a single node for a time but they are not exclusive to any 1 node.
- We've noticed that the failures happen most often with load, particularly failed sub-jobs are started later than their successful sibling sub-jobs (often after other siblings have already completed).
- We suspect that the sub-jobs are somehow considered completed by the master before they actually complete. Since they're not done the master sees them as failed. Later the sub-job really does complete (thus the console output says Success). We suspect this because we've added comments to "failed" jobs which look incomplete only to return later and see additional console logs.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is a bug in either the Jenkins "Set Build Name" plugin or the "Configuration Matrix" plugin.  When you use them both you're subject to a few bugs. First is the symptoms I described above.  Second is that the names set on builds can be wrong (race conditions mean that the wrong name can be applied).

There is a ticket open against Jenkins [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21526). Unfortunately there isn't currently a posted work-around.  We may simply stop using one of the plugins.